# Why does the PrinterJob[JAVA] Dialog still appear in the host computer even if accessed via network by others?

Tags: java, networking, tomcat, printing, dialog

Good day!

I am currently working on a program that needs to print a certain data directly to the printer. Fortunately, I've ran over the PrinterJob and the Printable utility in Java. Here is the code:

```
SWFPrintableUtil oUtil = new SWFPrintableUtil(sResult);//SWFPrintableUtil implements Printable

PrinterJob oPrinterJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

oPrinterJob.setPrintable(oUtil);

boolean bDoPrint = oPrinterJob.printDialog();
if ( bDoPrint )
{
    try 
    {
        oPrinterJob.print();
    } 
    catch (PrinterException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else
{
    ;
}
```

This is the code which implements the Printable interface:

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
    throws PrinterException {

    if (pageIndex != 0) 
    {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    System.out.println(csContents);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    int nX = (int) pageFormat.getImageableX();
    int nY = (int) pageFormat.getImageableY();
    g2d.translate(nX, nY);

    Font oFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 8);
    FontMetrics oMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(oFont);
    int nLineHeight = oMetrics.getHeight();

    BufferedReader oReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(csContents));

    String sLine = "";
    try 
    {
        while( (sLine = oReader.readLine()) != null )
        {
            nY = nY + nLineHeight;
            g2d.drawString(sLine, nX, nY);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Apparently, this code can do what I want. This code is triggered via a web page upon clicking a button. I've deployed this web page in Tomcat Server. Upon clicking the button, a dialog box appears for you to pick your printer and to layout your page(landscape/portrait, paper size etc etc.). Let's say I've deployed my website(via Tomcat) in "Computer A" and "computer B" accesses and tries to use the print functionality, what happens is that the pop-up dialog box for printing still appears to "Computer A". Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Oneb

Answer (score 0):

Because the code runs on the host computer. I guess you will need to download the document/printable to the remote computer ("Computer B") and print it there.

Comment: Hi! Good day, so your saying that my case is hopeless? There would be no way that the print set-up dialog box would appear in the computer accessing the host computer?

Comment: Yes I think so. I guess you have a servlet running on your tomcat server. And when you call the print job there, it will run on the server computer. I'm pretty sure there is no way to make Java show the Print setup dialog on the client computer. What you can try is to use a link on your website which will open the print dialog using `JavaScript`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestion.